# What does p:fragment do?

Tags: primefaces

I am trying to understand the sence of p:fragment of the PrimeFaces framework, but I just don't get it! The description on the [pimefaces page](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/fragment.xhtml) is sparingly written and I am not sure what to test in the given demo.

Could someone try to explain it to me in easy words?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<p:fragment>` is a form of syntactic sugar. It allows you to more easily define a section of your form that gets processed and updated by an ajax request. The request is called a partial ajax request because not all the components in the form are being processed. The ajax request is triggered by the `<p:commandButton>` in the PrimeFaces `<p:fragment>` ShowCase demo you are referencing.

Without `<p:fragment>` the PrimeFaces demo would be written like this:

```
<h:form>              
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
        <p:outputLabel for="ignored" value="Required" />
        <p:inputText id="ignored" required="true" />
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="5">
         <p:outputLabel for="txt" value="Text Value:" />
         <p:inputText id="txt" value="#{basicView.text}" />
         <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="outputTxt" process="txt"/>
         <h:outputText id="outputTxt" value="#{basicView.text}" />
     </h:panelGrid>                
</h:form>
```

In order to only process the `<p:inputText>` and only update my `<h:outputText>` I need to define them in with the `process` and `update` attributes of the `<p:commandButton>`.  When your dealing with a lot of components in a form you can see you where using `<p:fragment>` would be useful in making your JSF page more readable and keeps you from having to write all the component IDs you want to process and update.